# First order partial differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We need to solve the given first order partial differential equation :

$(y-xu)u_x$ + $(x+yu)u_y$ = $x^{2} + y^{2}$ .

I tried this :

$\frac{dx}{y-xu}$ = $\frac{dy}{x+yu}$ = $\frac{du}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ ,

First characteristic equation :  $\frac{x.dx - y.dy}{-u(x^{2} + y^{2})}$ = $\frac{du}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$  , which gives , $C_1$ = $u^{2}+x^{2} - y^{2}$ ,

I was a little skeptical about the second equation , so kindly tell if its correct or not  :

$\frac{y.dx + x.dy}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ = $\frac{du}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ , which gives , $C_2$ = $u-2xy$ ,

Are these constants correct ? 
Please help !

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{d(xy)}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{d(u)}{x^2+y^2}$ $\implies$ 
$xy=u+c_2$